# What am I talking about here?

Tags: riddle

My prefix is a big loud noise

My suffix are small animals

Somewhere in my middle is a synonym of beneath

Kids are my fans

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> Thundercats, thanks to @PaigeMeinke <s>Thunderbirds</s>

My prefix is a big loud noise

> Thunder

My suffix are small animals

> Cats, fits better with "small animal".. <s>Birds, although they can also be pretty big..</s>

Somewhere in my middle is a synonym of beneath

> Under

Kids are my fans

> They are..

Comment: @OnlyF perhaps rot13(GuhaqrePngf)

Comment: @PaigeMeinke got it :)

Comment: @PaigeMeinke, never heard of them, but thanks I'll add it in

Comment: it's an old cartoon

Comment: I think "Old kids are my fans" fits better

Comment: @Angelo - kids who watched it when it came out are now adults. Nostalgia makes fans of all ages, and is why I instantly knew the answer.